# Java util logging doesn't logs INFO messages even if the level is set to INFO

Tags: java, weblogic12c, java.util.logging

Java util logging doesn't logs INFO messages even if the level is set to INFO.

Given below is my properties file:

```
# Properties file which configures the operation of the JDK 
# logging facility.
 handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=INFO

# --- FileHandler --- 
# Override of global logging level 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=INFO
# Style of output (Simple or XML): 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
...
```

Deployed the application in weblogic server.The application is not logging any INFO messages, but its making SEVERE & WARNING messages.

Using code in a for loop for all handlers:

```
 LOGGER.getGlobal().getParent().getHandlers()[i].toString()+ " : "+ LOGGER.getGlobal().getParent().getHandlers()[i].getLevel()
```

these are the handlers used with their  levels:

```
oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ODLHandler :  ALL
oracle.core.ojdl.weblogic.DomainLogHandler :  WARNING
oracle.core.ojdl.logging.ConsoleHandler:  807
java.util.logging.FileHandler :  FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler : FINEST
```

Answer (score 0):

***Found the solution :***
Added the Application handler ;Registered handlers for the co.in.testApp.Process and its child loggers as below:

```
co.in.testApp.testProcess.handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
co.in.testApp.testProcess.useParentHandlers = false
co.in.testApp.testProcess.level=FINEST
```

After which the logs are reported properly.